# Large free-scrolling view that can return co-ordinates of press

Tags: android

I would like to display on screen a large view that the user can scroll in both directions (X and Y simultaneously, allowing diagonal scrolling as well). The view will be too large to to fit on screen so free-scrolling is absolutely vital. When the user presses on the view, I want to be able to know the co-ordinates of that press (co-ordinates of the actual view)..

I understand that using a `WebView` and somehow capturing the X/Y press co-ordinates could work, but I'm a little apprehensive of making one of my activities HTML when the rest of the app is native java.

What's the best way of achieving this in android?

Edit: Bumped. I know this is an old question but I never got an answer and would still love to know.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it in many ways, i think is a good solution put an ScrollView inside an HorizontalScrollView and handle the events.

Example:

**Layout:**

```
 <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:id="@+id/scrollHorizontal"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scrollVertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WateverViewYouWant/>

</ScrollView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

**Code (onCreate/onCreateView):**

```
final HorizontalScrollView hScroll = (HorizontalScrollView) value.findViewById(R.id.scrollHorizontal);
final ScrollView vScroll = (ScrollView) value.findViewById(R.id.scrollVertical);
vScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { //inner scroll listener         
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
});
hScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { //outer scroll listener         
    private float mx, my, curX, curY;
    private boolean started = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        curX = event.getX();
        curY = event.getY();
        int dx = (int) (mx - curX);
        int dy = (int) (my - curY);
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (started) {
                    vScroll.scrollBy(0, dy);
                    hScroll.scrollBy(dx, 0);
                } else {
                    started = true;
                }
                mx = curX;
                my = curY;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                vScroll.scrollBy(0, dy);
                hScroll.scrollBy(dx, 0);
                started = false;
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

If you invert the order in layout, invert also in java code, obviously change `<WateverViewYouWant/>` to your content.